# leaflet works in R but not in browser

Tags: r, leaflet

The following [code](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) works in R but not in the browser.

```
library(leaflet)
data(quakes)

map = leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(~long, ~lat, 
          popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(mag))
```

The browser only shows the location of the markers. I have disabled all browser extensions.

[image]

Question: how can I show the underlying map?

Session info:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] leaflet_1.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] htmlwidgets_0.8 shiny_1.0.0     magrittr_1.5    R6_2.2.0        htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.3     Rcpp_0.12.10    crosstalk_1.0.0 digest_0.6.12   xtable_1.8-2    httpuv_1.3.3    mime_0.5
```

Comment: Do you mean that you can't see the underlying map on the website you link, but if you run it locally in R, you can? And if so, does that not mean the problem is with your browser and not with R?

Comment: Yes, and possibly yes.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Yes, in Opera, Firefox (Linux) and MS Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an error getting the map tiles from the default map tile provider.

Until this is corrected in the leaflet package, I would suggest using another map tile provider for example:

```
map = leaflet(quakes[1:20,]) %>% 
addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.NatGeoWorldMap) %>% 
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, 
             popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(mag))
map
```

A full list of available map tile providers is available here:  http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html